# Woocommerce product category filter dosn't update ACF

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

1. There is custom filed created to display second place for Seo text just under products on product category archive pages.
2. When entering category from menu bar - the different description in ACF correctly changes according to chosen category.
3. The problem is - WHEN - we are in any of these product categories and want to use product category **filter** from the side bar. Then nothing is changing. Category changes but description from ACF stays from previous category. That should work like this, we ar in A category, but want to filter products with B category filter, after applying that filter there should be updated page with b category products and updated ACF Seo description. How can we resolve that?

My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_extra_description' );
function my_extra_description() {

global $wp_query;
apply_filters( 'acf/update_value', $value, $post_id, $field, $original );
# get the query object
$category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
#get the cat ID
$category_ID = $category->term_id;

#get the field
$contenu_categorie = get_field( 'contenu_categorie', 'category_'.$category_ID );
#if we have data, show it
if( $contenu_categorie ){
echo $contenu_categorie;
}

}
```

Plase help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect your code to do?  you've copied the source code for `acf/update_value` but as you have it... it won't do anything. Please clarify your question and review your code.

Comment: https://mariomenezi.pl -> pass: 0104 , please check it how it behaves live. The custom field under products updates when you enter different product category from main nav menu, but as soon as you choose product category from the filter then extra description under products won't change.